# Save state of dynamically added View

Tags: android

The problem is that if I have an EditText in a layout.xml the View's state is saved e.g. on orientation change. When I add an EditText from code it doesn't happen.

TextView.setFreezesText() doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
View.setSaveEnabled(boolean)
```

Its enabled by default, but as the doc says:

> the view still must have an id assigned to it (via setId()) for its state to be saved

Answer (score 0):

You should save your EditText content on your activity's [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method which is called when you change the orientation of an activity. 
Check out getPreferences method as well to save your activity's state when it is paused.

Comment: Ok, so there is no built-in thing which could do this?

Comment: Well, no . There's isn't an autosave functionality to save all your data to  provide more flexibility and save only what you want to.